# Regex to match only one character sequence within string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in a jList that I am looking to split with a regex (for future simplicity if requirements change)

The string looks a lot like this:

ID: GF68464, Name: productname

the ID could be any combination of letters and numbers and could be any length.

I only want the ID to be matched, i.e excluding "ID: " and anything after the comma following the ID.

Here is what I have thus far but it doesn't seem to do what I ask it to

```
[^ID: ][a-zA-Z1-9][^,^.]
```

FURTHER INFO (EDIT)

I plan on extracting the ID to match against an array. (hence the need for a regex). Could this be done a different way?

Comment: So you just want to match anything after `"ID: "`?

Comment: Anything after ID: until a comma is reached (,)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ID:\s*(\w+),
```

and extract the 1st capturing group. You can also use lookarounds (+1 to @p.s.w.g).

---

```
String str = "ID: GF68464, Name: productname";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("ID:\\s*(\\w+),").matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

```
GF68464
```

Comment: nope, that appears to just match the entire string. Do forgive me if I'm making a faux pas

Comment: You can extract just the groups in `()`'s using the `Matcher.group` method - which should include ONLY the parenthesized text, and not the rest of the matched string.

Comment: @CameronMiller It *matches* the entire string, but it *captures* the ID and the text following the comma in separate groups. You have to use the `.group` method to extract the relevant capture group.

Comment: Did the job. You sir, are a legend.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<ID:\s*)\w+(?=,)
```

This will match any sequence of one or more word characters preceded by `"ID:"` and any number of white space characters, and followed by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a non-capturing group. There are already some fairly high-quality examples of doing this in Java on SO - for example, this question: [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)

Comment: I believe, s?he needs capturing group.

Comment: You could either place the "ID: " portion in a non-capturing group, or place the ID itself in a capture group and then only extract that group from the returned match. Either should work.

Comment: I will admit that capture groups are probably the more straight-forward solution, but non-capturing groups are still a handy trick to know.

Answer (score 0):

Create a regex like /^[a-z A-Z 0-9]*,/ then use can use match function and use value match[0] like

```
var regex = /^[a-z A-Z 0-9]*\,/;
var matches = your_string.match(regex);
var required_value = matches[0];
```

hope this helps

Comment: No, this won't work. It will reject the `:` in the `ID: `. You could add it to the character class, but then it would catch a lot more than what OP wanted. Also, you use a start anchor, but OP never said that it should only match the at the start of the string / line. Finally, this appears to be JavaScript, but the question was specifically tagged as Java.

Comment: I am sorry I took it a JavaScript query and thanks for clarification